# Onde devo colocar a ConnectionString em Aplicações Windows Forms com EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms

Estou com o seguinte erro usando Entity Framework:

> Additional information: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Pelo que pesquisei deste erro o **EF** não encontrou minha `ConnectionString` e utiliza a padrão

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ResenhaInformalContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Estou usando um **WINDOWS FORMS APPLICATION** e uma **CLASS LIBRARY** de infraestrutura já coloquei a `ConnectionString` no App.Config, tanto da Class Library onde o Entity Framework está instalado, quanto no W.F que é onde acontece o start da aplicação.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ResenhaInformalContext" connectionString="Data Source=RENAN-   NB\ESPACOCULTURA;Initial Catalog=ResenhaInformalContext;Persist Security     Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=renan010203;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Qual é a forma de resolver este erro ?

Comment: No [Package Manager Console](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console) execute o seguinte comando: `Install-Package EntityFramework`

Comment: Estou com ele instalado na camada de infraestrutura... Você diz que devo instalar também na aplicação WF?

Comment: Vc adicionou a referencia do EF em seu projeto?

Comment: Isso geralmente ocorre porque o EF nao instalado direito, o comando acima e p reinstalar ele corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa ter o Entity Framework referenciado também no seu projeto principal.

Importante ressaltar que a *connection string* utilizada será aquela que estiver no **`app.config`** (ou **`web.config`**) do projeto principal - isso também vale para rodar migrations, a *connection string* será sempre do projeto que estiver marcado como ***startup project***.

Comment: O EF não precisa estar referenciado. Pode apenas estar na Class Library de Infraestrutura. Seria legal colocar um exemplo do `Web.config` para ele.

Comment: Tem certeza? Então só preciso ter o `configSections` no projeto principal?

Comment: Exatamente. A leitura da *Config Section* pode ser feita apenas pela *Class Library*.

Comment: Deixe só eu confirmar, eu preciso ter no app.config da class library a seção do EF (e o configSections, claro) e no projeto principal só preciso da connection string?

Comment: Exatamente. Experimente criar um projeto com a DLL de *Models* separada.

Comment: Resolvi o erro da seguinte forma: Coloquei na minha classe de contexto o código.
`public ResenhaInformalContext()
            : base("ResenhaInformalContext")
        {
            var chamada = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
        }`

Vi isso em um outro exemplo desse erro com um projeto Console Application. Testei e funcionou. Porém não sei o que ele faz se alguém puder me explicar.

Comment: Vi o comentário do @jbueno, e fiz o teste no meu programa. Antes eu tinha dois app.config, um na Class Library e outro no projeto principal, porque achava que o projeto utilizava os dois arquivos. Comentei o app.config da Class Library deixando somente no projeto principal e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, vc falou no primeiro comentário que o EF não precisa estar referenciado no projeto principal, porém hoje mexendo numa parada exatamente igual a essa aqui, só funcionou quando referenciei no projeto principal. em alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: @RenanOliveira Faça uma nova pergunta, por favor.